# Call same python script in for loop from another python script

Tags: python

I have a scenario, where I have to call a certain Python script multiple times in another python script.

script1:

```
import sys

path=sys.argv

print "I am a test"
print "see! I do nothing productive."
print "path:",path[1]
```

script2:

```
import subprocess

l=list()
l.append('root')
l.append('root1')
l.append('root2')

for i in l:
    cmd="python script1.py i"
    subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
```

Here, my issue is that in script 2, I am not able to replace the value of "i" in the for loop. 
Can you help with that?

Comment: Just create the string in the for loop. `cmd = "python script1.py " + str(i)`. You are hardcoding `i` as a character, and not using its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to substitute the value of i into the string you can concatenate it:

```
cmd="python script1.py "+i
```

or format it into the string:

```
cmd="python script1.py %s"%i
```

Either way you need to use the variable i instead of the string i.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
cmd="python script1.py %s" % i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.Popen` with a lists:

```
import subprocess

paths = ['root', 'root1', 'root2']

for path in paths:
    subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script1.py', path])
```